# Android 6 Samsung Touchwiz launcher icons are bigger than of non samsung apps

Tags: android, icons, samsung-mobile

Anbdroid stock Samsung icons are displayed bigger then non Samsung icons. I took a screenshot of my custom icon 144x144 px next to a stock Samsung browser icon, which is displayed at least 6 pixel larger.

[image: samsung icon vs. other icons]

The reason must be the .qmg decoded icon which is Samsung propietary. I have already looked for an .qmg encoder but there is no official way. 
I tried the samsung theme designer for older Bada devices which is able to create qmg files (I have replaced the background with my desired icon and exported the whole theme, replaced the ending to .zip and exported my background) [Samsung Theme Designer](http://developer.samsung.com/bada-themes/tools-sdks/Samsung-Theme-Designer-2-0-4). Unfortunately android is not able to decode my created icon.

Is there a way to stretch a normal app icon to the same oversize like the stock Samsung icon or is there another way to encode a .qmg icon? I have found a decoder only tool on [xda-developers: [TOOL] Converter QMG/ASTC->PNG](http://forum.xda-developers.com/note-4/themes-apps/tool-converter-qmg-png-t2916486), which uses the decoder on the device to create png files.

**Update**

I did some research and noticed a really strange thing. If I create an empty Icon with a thin single boarder, the icon will be stretched to the same size like the Samsung icons. If I fill up the icon content, it will be shrinked.

[image]

[image]

Is this a Samsung Touchwiz behaviour or a general Android 6 issue? I don't have any non Samsung phones on my pool to test it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the solution in a stock Samsung Application AndroidManifest.xml

You need to add the following line into the `<application>` tag in the mainfest.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.samsung.android.icon_container.has_icon_container" android:value="true"/>
```

This works with *.png and *.qmg icons too.